# Insert a row in a table with 2 rows have foreign key with an other (linq)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Let say i have 2 table, person and sharing.

```
tblPerson
username(varchar)
```

and table sharing

```
tblsharing
sharingperson (varchar) link to table person
sharedperson (varchar)  link to table person
```

I'm trying to insert a new row in table sharing, but it said "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
here is my code, temp is a new instance of tblSharing

```
 tblSharing temp= new tblSharing();
 temp.sharingperson = db.tblPersons.Single(x =>x.username==strSharingPerson).username;
 temp.sharedperson = db.tblPersons.Single(x => x.username == sharedperson).username;                    
 db.tblSharings.InsertOnSubmit(temp);
```

I was tried another way is just assign text like:

```
temp.sharingperson = "username_sharing"
temp.sharedperson = "username_shared"                    
db.tblSharings.InsertOnSubmit(temp);
```

Is anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: where and how do you instantiate temp? If temp is not instantiated, it is likely to be null. Furthermore, if your `.Single(...)` does not return any row, it will be null, causing an exception on your `.username`.

Comment: `tblPerson temp = new tblPerson();` that how i instance temp, and i'm sure that strSharingPerson and sharedperson already exist in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 things that can be null in the code you posted.
If you tell us on which line you get the error, maybe we can narrow it down :)

1) db.tblPersons.Single(x =>x.username==strSharingPerson) can be null - but you said you checked and it is not...

2) db.tblPersons.Single(x => x.username == sharedperson) same story

3) temp can be null, but you said you created it before assigning anything.

4) db can also be null. If you have checked in the database that these records exist, that doesn;t mean that you are in your code talking to a live connection. When you debug, is your db set to a correct instance, or is it null?

If all 4 of these things are not null, as far as I can see your code should work.
If this is not the case, we are either missing relevant code here, or other relevant information, and you should provide us with it (for instance, on which exact line yu get the exception :) )

Comment: case 3 :( oh...how careless am i. I should know it, i assigned it to a function that return null

Comment: "Whenever we eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however impossible, must be the truth" - Sherlock Holmes :)